# How to return value on timeout from Akka 1.3 future?

Tags: akka

Given the following:

```
import akka.dispatch.{FutureTimeoutException, Future}

val f1 = Future({ Thread.sleep(2000); 0}, 500)

f1.onException {
  case timeout: FutureTimeoutException => -1
}

f1.recover {
    case timeout: FutureTimeoutException => -2
}

println(f1.get)
```

Why do I still get an exception? Is there a way to recover from a timeout such that a real value is returned instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building off what Victor said, if you want to recover from a particular type of failure with a `Future` using `recover` you need to be aware that `recover` returns a new `Future` and that's the one that you need to call `get` on in order to get the recover functionality.  Something like this:

```
val f1 = Future({ Thread.sleep(2000); 0}, 500)
val withRecover = f1.recover {
  case timeout: FutureTimeoutException => -2
}
println(withRecover.get)
```

Or you could just chain it onto the `Future` creation like so:

```
val f1 = Future({ Thread.sleep(2000); 0}, 500).recover {
  case timeout: FutureTimeoutException => -2
}
println(f1.get)
```

**EDIT**

So it looks like things work different in Akka 1.3 with their own internal futures as compared to the Futures and Promises from scala 2.10.  In Akka 1.3, recover only works for non-timeout situations.  I rolled an example of how to work around that, but you really should upgrade if possible to get on the latest scala and akka:

```
import akka.dispatch._
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.{ NANOSECONDS ⇒ NANOS, MILLISECONDS ⇒ MILLIS }
import akka.actor.Actor

object FutureTest {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val f1: Future[Int] = Future({
            Thread.sleep(2000)
            0
        }, 500)

        val f2 = recoverTO(f1) {            
            -2
        }

        println(f2.get)
    }

  def recoverTO[T, A >: T](fut:Future[T])(f: => A): Future[A] = {
    val fa = new DefaultCompletableFuture[A](fut.timeoutInNanos, NANOS)
    fut.onTimeout { future =>
      fa completeWithResult f
    }
    fut.onComplete {
      fa complete _.value.get
    }    
    fa
  }    
}
```

Comment: Still fails... https://gist.github.com/francois/6050979 I must be doing something wrong? Scala 2.9.1, Akka 1.3.1.

Comment: Try changing the exception type in the case statement to `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException`. My guess is that you're not catching the right exception thus not activating the recover functionality.

Comment: the exception's full name is `akka.dispatch.FutureTimeoutException`, as evidenced by the stack trace.

Comment: @FrançoisBeausoleil, I updated my answer to account for how things work in akka 1.3...

Answer (score 0):

Futures are write-once, and as such the only way to modify a Future that has a value (or exception) is to return a *new* Future. Check the return type of "recover".